# Stochastic processes and infection propagation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

In Tijms's book *Understanding Probability*, I found the following example.

> Consider a population of $m$ individuals, some of whom are
> infected and the others are susceptible. Initially one individual is infected. The
> times between contacts between any two individuals of the population have an
> exponential distribution with rate $\mu$. The times between the various contacts are
> independent of each other. If a susceptible individual comes in contact with an
> infected individual, the susceptible individual becomes infected. Once infected,
> an individual stays infected. What stochastic process describes the spread of the disease?
>
> **Solution.** The key to the solution is the fact that the minimum of $r$ independent
> random variables having exponential distributions with rates $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_r$ is
> again exponentially distributed with rate $\mu_1 + \dots + \mu_r$.
> Denote by the random variable $X(t)$ the number of infected individuals at time
> $t$. Then, by the memoryless property of the exponential distribution, the process
> $\{X(t)\}$ is a continuous-time Markov chain with state space $I = \{1, 2, \dots , m\}$.
> How do we find the transition rates? If there are $i$ infected individuals, the time
> until one of the $m -i$ susceptible individuals becomes infected is the smallest
> of $(m - i)i$ independent exponentials each having rate $\mu$ and hence this
> time has an exponential distribution with rate $(m − i)i\mu$. It now follows that
> the transition rates $q_{i,i+1}$ are given by
> $$ q_{i,i+1} = (m − i)i\mu \qquad \text{for }i = 1, 2, \dots, m - 1.$$
> The other transition rates $q_{ij}$ are zero because of the assumption that an infected
> individual stays infected once it is infected. Note that state $m$ is an absorbing
> state with leaving rate $\nu_m = 0$.

I mostly agree with the solution, but I do not understand why $i$ infected individuals interact with $m-i$ susceptible individuals with probability 1.

I think that this solution does not consider the case that some of the $i$ infected individuals can interact between themselves (the wording of the problem does not exclude this possibility).

Shouldn't we keep in mind this thing when calculating the transition rates?
If so, how to model this more complex disease propagation model?

Comment: I guess the solution to your dilemma lies withing: "The times between contacts between **any two** individuals of the population have an exponential distribution with rate . The times between the various contacts are independent of each other."

Comment: @denklo oh, so does it mean that the time required for all the $m(m-1)$ possible contacts to happen is distributed as an exponential with rate $\mu$?

Comment: No. There are $m(m-1)$  possible contacts when there is just $1$ infected. ONE possible contact is distributed as an exponential with rate $\mu$ . So the first contact between a random individual and the infected one is distributed as an exponential with rate ${\mu m(m-1)}$ (for the distribution of the minimum) if they all have the same rate,

Comment: @Alfredo yes, I agree for the number of possible contacts. But then, for modelling the progress of the illness, we should keep track only of the expected number of contacts between $i$ ill people and $(m-i)$ susceptible individuals. I do not see how this gives the transition rate $(m-i)i\mu$.

Comment: Imagine you have $6$ ill people and $15$ not infected from a $21$ people population. How many contacts are between ill and not ill? Each of the $6$ ill's ones can infect each one of the $15$ not ill, so there are $(m-i)i$ contacts (in this case $6\times 15$). As each one of these contacts occurs with a rate of $\mu$, the minimum (the first contact between that $(m-i)i$ possible contacts) occurs with rate $\mu (m-i)i$.

Comment: @Alfredo ok, I see, so everything that matters is how many contacts are possible, not the probability that such a contact between a ill and a sane person is $\frac{(m-i)i}{{m \choose 2}}$.